# Why request to my website from Chrome sometimes sent via HTTP and sometimes via HTTP/2?

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser, http2

When i enter my website URL in the address bar and press enter, the request is sent via HTTP, but if i open another tab and enter the same URL and press enter, the request sent via HTTP/2. If i then close the browser and re open it, the request send via HTTP. Why is it happening?

Comment: HTTP or HTTP/1.1 over HTTPS?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 over HTTPS

Comment: Odd. Does your site pass this HTTP/2 test:https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test with two green boxes? Are you sitting behind any proxy or Anti-virus software that is intercepting the request? Are you able to share the URL?

Comment: My website Is in a private network (so i can't share the URL) and it's possible that there is an antivirus that intercepts, but i see the request been sent via HTTP/2 in the browser's development mode - before any antivirus may intercept. also, my webserver (nginx) is not supporting HTTP/2 so i don't want that requests will be sent via HTTP/2

Comment: If it doesn't support HTTP/2 then it can't be sent via HTTP/2! So either Chrome is reporting this wrong (never heard of that before) or something else is going on...

Comment: I figured out that i forgot that i have another nginx server in front of the web server i mentioned above, that do support's HTTP/2. that explains why the browser sent an HTTP/2 requests. but not explains the main question i asked.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you have two IPs for your domain, and one supports HTTP/2 and one does not. You connect to the first, use HTTP/1.1 but during this time you use another subdomain (e.g. static.example.com) and it hares the IP with the second IP address for your main site. In this case, the browser may reuse the second IP over the same HTTP/2 connection. Do you have multiple IP addresses? Are there subdomains on those same IP addresses?